# Why does Doxygen still executed pdftex despite `GENERATE_LATEX=NO`?

Tags: documentation, doxygen, tex

I've a reasonable large C/C++ project and want to generate only a HTML version of the documentation by Doxygen. In my `Doxyfile` I've written

```
GENERATE_LATEX = NO
```

In deed, there is no `latex` directory in the specified output directory; just `html`. However, I'm getting output by *pdfTex* on stderr:

```
...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (TeX Live 2010)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./_formulas.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
...
Output written on _formulas.dvi (279 pages, 49376 bytes).
Transcript written on _formulas.log.
...
```

Why?

Doxygen's [installation instructions](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/install.html) list LaTeX as an optional (additional) tool, which is not required. Thus I assume, it is not required for basic functionality of HTML generation.

How can I make Doxygen not execute `pdfTex`? (*no, I do not want to uninstall *TeX on my machine*)

Comment: I presume doxygen is using pdftex to generate your forumlas, hence the file name `_formulas.log`. Try running doxygen on a minimal documented file (e.g. a single file with a class that does nothing and with no formulas in the documentation) and see if you still get that output on stderr.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file _formulas.tex is created as the result of using [formulas](http://www.doxygen.org/formulas.html).
If you want formulas without the need for LaTeX you can set USE_MATHJAX to YES.